# How to looping in python with raster dataset

Tags: python

I have a multiband raster (84 bands). I am reading the raster using GDAL and converting it to numpy array. In numpy when I am checking the array shape it is showing as 84 = bands, 3 = row and 5 = col. I want to compute the ratio between the band(0)/band(n+1) for n in 1 to 84. Thus, I am able to get 83 arrays, each array represents pixel-by-pixel ratio. For example, I have:

```
Band 1
    [[1,    2,   3,   4,  5],
     [6,    7,   8,   9,  10],
     [11,   12,  13,  14, 15]]
Band 2
    [[21,   22,   23,   24,  25],
     [26,   27,   28,   29,  30],
     [31,   32,   33,   34,  35]]
Band 3
    [[31,   32,   33,   34,  35],
     [36,   37,   38,   39,  40],
     [41,   42,   43,   44,  45]]
...
...
Band84
```

I need to loop through all the bands in such a way that I get these: Band2/Band1; Band3/Band1; ... ; Band84/Band1

```
Band2/Band1
    [[1/21,   2/22,   3/23,  4/24,  5/25],
     [6/26,   7/27,   8/28,  9/29,  10/30],
     [11,31,  12/32,  13/33, 14/34, 15/35]]
```

And so on...

There is any way to vectorize this calculation?

I really appreciate your advice.

Comment: Isn't it just `X[0] / X[1:]`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you need

```
Band2/Band1; Band3/Band1 ... Band84/Band1

Band3/Band2; Band4/Band2 ... Band84/Band2

...

Band84/Band83
```

It should be something like this

```
for a in range(0, len(all_bands)-1): 
    for b in range(a+1, len(all_bands)): 
        print( all_bands[b]/all_bands[a] )
```

Comment: Thanks furas, it is a mean to vectorize the solution. Thank you.